# Gutsworld - a Graphic Novel about a Puritan, Victorian-Era Society trapped in a Whale-like Creature

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story

What I'm looking for now is *Visual Evidence* of this thing's existence. Everything I've got together so far is below, and in the comments.

---

It was about a Puritan, Victorian-era society trapped in a whale-like creature. I remember it being called "Gutsworld", but upon looking it up, all I could find was a Wrestling Organization by the same name.

Looking up `Civilization inside whale` and related search terms came up with nothing.

It was a Graphic Novel, available to order on the internet, I think. Earlier than 2017 but after 2013, at least that's when I came across it; might have been made earlier.

---

[Here](http://www.wetasphalt.com/content/round-6) is the only living mention of it on any site I can find. The link on the webpage takes me to a dead IP address. I put this into the Wayback Machine and it came up with [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111201622/forum.newsarama.com/showthread.php?t=150677) (I'm not very experienced using this, so if anyone can get more info out of it that would be a huge help).

Apparently the reason it's a dead IP is because [Newsarama, the site that hosted these forums, was bought and has shut down the forum service. They deleted the entire archives of the forums when they did so.](http://www.theouthousers.com/forum/the-asylum/has-newsarama-done-away-with-its-forums-t76820.html)

So, it would appear there is more to this tale than meets the eye.

Comment: I've edited in the `[illustrated-story]` tag as that seems to be closest to what you are describing, if that isn't appropriate you can remove it yourself, however.

Comment: This 2008 article: http://www.wetasphalt.com/content/round-6 mentions it: _Speaking of comics, the inestimably strange and wonderful Gutsworld number 1 is available in its entirety online. It's about a civilization that has developed inside the body of an enormous leviathan, after said monster swallowed whole a ship 150 years ago._  but I can't find anything else about it.

Comment: @Ayshe I remember seeing it, and I remember images of it, and this lets me know it exists, but it appears that all trace of this comic has been scrubbed from the internet

Comment: Maybe try asking on Newsarama's facebook page or contacting wetasphalt.com, if you haven't already.

Comment: A check at a prominent vendor (Mile High Comics) website, and at [comics.org](http://comics.org) shows no entries for a comic named *Gutsworld*. It's possible that it was either *only* available online, or that it was originally released in some language other than English, and its translated name was different.

Comment: I'm guessing it may have been a webcomic with plans to release in print...

Comment: Put in "Gutsville" at archive.org. It had an associated website, gutsville.com. Only 3 issues were ever published.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This is *Gutsville*

[image]

According to the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gutsville):

> In 1846 an English ship called the Daphne heads out to reach
>   Australia. The ship never makes it, as it, and all of its passengers
>   (including slaves, zealous missionaries, and English settlers) are
>   swallowed up by some gargantuan, oceanic beast. Skip forward to the
>   present day and the descendants of the original passengers are living
>   in Gutsville, a shanty town within the belly of this mysterious
>   creature.

I found it by putting the URL in [this website](https://archive.fo/ZT7bO), which showed that the Newsrama forum URL had been linked from the above Wikipedia page.

It appears that the website Wetasphalt had misremembered it the same way as the OP: as *Gutsworld*.

It's not terribly obscure, having been published by Image Comics, but it was first written in 2007, so it was early enough.

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for this everywhere! I was so worried I'd never find this again.

Comment: Nice. I even asked the guy from Wetasphalt if he could remember it but he came up a blank

Comment: Sorry about only awarding the bounty now, it's my first time using one and I assumed it automatically awarded it once a green tick was given.